# Кастомный RadioButton с описанием

Tags: android, customview

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить к RadioButton описание?
Может, существуют уже готовые библиотеки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

А в чем отличие от родного RadioButton?

Эффект "пузырика" добавляется через android:background="?selectableItemBackground"

На Android Arsenal [целый раздел](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/82?sort=created) с Radiobutton

Comment: Оригинальный компонент не поддерживает описание

Comment: А, ну да. Тогда изучите арсенал, может там есть что-то. Если нет - пишите, придумаем как такой сделать

Comment: Пытался найти, но безуспешно. На текущий момент имею свой компонент с RadioButton без текста и двумя TextView, но из этого способа реализации вытекают две проблемы: нужен собственный RadioGroup и на RadioButton можно нажать, что, конечно, недопустимо, однако блокировка компонента проблему не решит.